# Uniqueness constraint on secondary relation

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to model a simple poll system, I have 4 tables

```
Election
 id, title, description

Candidate
 id, electionId, name

User
 id, (other user details)...

Vote
 userId, candidateId
```

There is a 1-n relation from Election to Candidate. If someone runs in multiple elections, they are listed as multiple candidates.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to constrain each user to one vote in each election at the database level. If I create an `electionId` column in `Vote` I create inconsistent or redundant data, but I can't think of any other way to constrain the data like that otherwise.

I feel like this has to be a common problem but I don't know what to call it so my last half an hour of searching hasn't been fruitful. What's the correct approach here?

Comment: Also, is secondary relation the right term for the relationship from Vote to Election?

Comment: In the relational model, Election and Candidate are relations, and the 1-n cardinality applies to the (electionId, id) pair of columns in the Candidate table. Also, redundancy doesn't have to mean inconsistency, in fact it can be used to ensure consistency. See my answer to [How do I ensure integrity between unrelated tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413488/how-do-i-ensure-integrity-between-unrelated-tables/43416765#43416765)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `Candidate`'s PK to be a composite of `electionId, name` or at least make that combination a unique constraint in `Candidate`.

Then you would change `Vote` to be `userId, electionId, name` where the PK is `userId, electionId` and there is a FK pointing to `Candidate`'s `electionId, name` which is now unique.

This means that userId and electionId are unique for the vote table and there is no redundancy left.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with your current schema by adding validation before the insert into Vote (in mysql this is done with a TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT). You'd select all votes by that particular user, joined with candidate on candidateId, and make sure none of the electionIds match the election Id of the candidate the vote is for.

This is completely normalized but expensive. Sometimes it's worth adding redundant fields for the sake of performance. I'd add electionId to Vote in this schema so that inserts don't need such an expensive validation.