# How to model this relation in a relational database?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have the following situation:
- Client  (ID)
- Contract  (ID, ClientID)
- ClientEmployee (ID, ClientId)

A Client can have many Contracts, and a Client can have many ClientEmployees.

For any Contract, I need to associate the ClientEmployees working on it.

My solution, at the moment, is the easy one, where I build a many-to-many 
relation between the Contracts and the ClientEmployees.
- ContractClientEmployee (ID, ContractID, ClientEmployeeID)

With this design, there is no way (at database design level) to prevent a ClientEmployee to be associated to a Contract of another Client, that would be an error, of course.

I feel that there must be a 'better' solution, that captures in the schema this further constraint, but I cannot figure out how... :-(

UPDATE: I received two valid and very good answers, that point, more or less, to the same concepts for a good solution. I accepted Renzo's one because it came first... sorry, reaanb...

Comment: See my answer to [How do I ensure integrity between unrelated tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413488/how-do-i-ensure-integrity-between-unrelated-tables/43416765#43416765)

Comment: Wow... It looks complicated! :-) I need time to read it well... for the moment, thank you very much! I will tell you what I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, in which the basic idea is to define as primary keys for Contract and Employee a composite key, formed by the primary key of the client, and a numeric value used to distinguish between the different contracts and employees “inside” a client.

```
Client(ClientId, ClientData),
   primary key ClientId
Contract(ClientId, ContrNum, ContractData)
   primary key (ClientId, ContrNum)
   ClientId foreign key for Client
Employee(ClientId, EmplNum, EmplData)
   primary key (ClientId, EmpNum)
   ClientId foreign key for Client
EmployeeContract(ClientId, EmpNum, ContrNum)
   primary key (ClientId, EmpNum, ContrNum)
   (ClientId, EmpNum) foreign key for Employee
   (ClientId, ContrNum) foreign key for Contract
```

In this way the consistency among the data is maintained at the database level through the different foreign keys: when you insert a new record for EmployeeContract this will surely be an employee working for the same client for which the contract is stipulated.

Comment: This looks really interesting! I have to think to the implications of such a solution, but you already were more than useful, giving me so much to think... Thank you, for the moment, I will come back with my comments once I understand it in all the nuances... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> For any Contract, I need to associate the ClientEmployees working on it.

if above sentence means a one-to-many relation between Contract and ClientEmployees , in ClientEmployee you can use ContractID instead of ClientID:

```
- Client (ID)
- Contract (ID, ClientID)
- ClientEmployee (ID, ContractID)
```

in this case you can define a ClientEmployee only if there is a Contract for the client.

Let me now if it works for your case or not.

Comment: No, because the clientemployee must be of a specific client, and cannot work in contracts that are not associated to the client...