# Making sure an entity belongs to another in an ER diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship

So in the diagram I am trying to construct Every customer has a credit card. And then the order entity has customer ID and Card Number as foreign keys. How do I make sure these are related and an order does not have a customer with a credit card he does not own.

[image]

I figured I could do this through a payment entity. Tell me what you think.

Comment: See my answer to [How do I ensure integrity between unrelated tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413488/how-do-i-ensure-integrity-between-unrelated-tables/43416765#43416765)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first question I have is if a credit card has a foreign key to a user then does the order need to have both a customer id and credit card id? Could you not figure out the customer from the credit card that has been used?

I don't believe you can have a foreign key that is restricted by data in a table, the best validation (database) side of things is foreign keys, so have a foreign key on the customer table for customer ID and a foreign key on credit card table for credit card id. If you have to have both pieces of information in the table then I suspect best solution is to add some business logic to check that the card belongs to said customer before inserting it into the table.

This type of business logic can be done though c# or through stored procedures.

But the pseudo code would be something like:

```
public void InsertOrder(int customerId, int creditCardId) 
{
    var customer = db.GetCustomer(customerId);
    var cards = db.GetCardsBelongingToCustomer(customerId);
    if(cards.Any(card => card.Id == creditCardId))
    {
      db.InsertOrder(new Order{});;
    }
}
```

Comment: between the customer and a credit card I have a owns relationship .Customer owns a credit card.Which is achieved with a foreign key in an sql table.

Comment: Yes, so if Customer owns credit card, could an order not own a credit card? This way you could map an order to a Customer Via the card table 

    `SELECT Customer.Id
    From Order
    LEFT JOIN CreditCard ON Order.CreditCardId = CreditCard.Id 
    LEFT JOIN Custoner ON CreditCard.CustomerId = Customer.Id`

Comment: yeah the thing is , it is just designing the table using diagram designing tools. It is not about sql. Ill link a picture of the diagram.